# Regex to replace text between two alphanumeric digits - python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the timestamp like this `2022-04-13T00':'21':'45Z','source':'natwest'`.

I want to replace **':'** which is in between **T** suffix with two numerical digits following by ':' two numerical digits following by ':' and **Z** prefix two numerical digits.

Replace **':'** with **AND**

I have tried to use this regex.
`'.*'`

But it is replacing the one which is after **source** but I don't want that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to obtain `2022-04-13T00'AND'21'AND'45Z','source':'natwest'`?

Comment: No, I mean 2022-04-13T00AND21AND45Z','source':'natwest'

Comment: `re.sub(r"(?<=T\d{2}).*?(?=\d{2}Z)", lambda x: x.group().replace("':'", 'AND'), text)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Can we directly replace using regex rather than group

Comment: You want to replace multiple occurrences of a substring between two patterns, right? With `re`, you cannot do it without a callable as the replacement argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite strict pattern description, where you can make the substitution of both ':' in one go, using a capture group to regenerate the two digits that sit between the two occurrences:

```
s = "2022-04-13T00':'21':'45Z','source':'natwest'"
result = re.sub(r"(?<=T\d\d)':'(\d\d)':'(?=\d\dZ)", r"AND\1AND", s)
```